# Unable to push git after rolling back 1 step

Tags: git

I issued the following command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This stepped the code back 1 push, as I wanted.  I then made a few changes to the code and did:

```
git add -A
git push
```

And got back...

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

So I did the following to try to force it:

```
git push -f
```

with the result:

```
Counting objects: 360, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (220/220), done.
Writing objects: 100% (230/230), 1.97 MiB | 354.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 230 (delta 81), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects (230/230) (18348 ms)
remote: Storing pack file and index...  done (284 ms)
To <url>
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (TF401026: The ForcePush permission is required to perform this action.)
error: failed to push some refs to '<url>'
```

So how can I push this code to be the current master code?

The git is stored on visualstudio.com if that makes a difference.

Comment: You don't have `The ForcePush permission`. That's controlled by the remote host. Why not do a `revert` instead of reset?

Comment: I've listed what I have done.  If there is a way to fix it, please suggest it in an answer.

Comment: You can't force push because the remote host is obviously blocking you. Why did you `git reset --hard HEAD~1` instead of reverting the commit that needed to be removed?

Comment: I searched for how to roll back 1 commit on here, and this was a chosen answer by a user.

Comment: Most likely you misunderstood the context of the question, the command is `correct` but not for this scenario. The command will reset your local repo to the second-to-latest commit but it means you're out of sync with `origin`. You likely just wanted `git revert <hash>` https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/undoing-changes#!revert

Comment: Which result in `error: could not revert <hash>... Changed nodes again`

Comment: And now I can't compile my code.  This has really screwed it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helion is providing good advice, id recommending taking it. Basically what I would do in your scenario is the following:

First, follow the instructions of the original error message which included `git pull`, only in this instance I would use `git pull --rebase`.

So run `git pull --rebase <remote name> <branch name>`

Once you have that, your changes that you made after you reset will be replayed on top of the file that you previously deleted.

Your git log will look something like:

```
commit 0d703fc79bf996e04275888dd6732e77048b2748
Author: Peter Foti <peterfoti@me.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 13 14:18:39 2014 -0500

    Good Commit

commit 812fad226565382875021236690f74e96a54a16a
Author: Peter Foti <peterfoti@me.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 13 14:18:03 2014 -0500

    Commit you previously deleted
```

Then what you can do is revert the changes of the commit you previously reset by writing:

`git revert <sha hash of bad commit>`

What the revert is going to do is actually create another commit which reverses the bad commit. So it will quite literally undo everything that commit does in the form of a new commit.

Once you've done that you will be able to `git push` successfully.

Comment: So I would do `git pull --rebase master master` then `git revert <latest hash I dont want>`?

Comment: "remote" is commonly `origin`. Where ever you `push`/`pull` from

Comment: The code seems to be reverted then updated correctly now.  However, my prompt reads: `[(<hash>...)|REBASE +0 ~1 -0]>`  Is there something I need to do?

Comment: @JamesKorden yes to your first comment, it sounds like you did that and it worked. Im not sure about the last bit of your prompt id need to see fully output.